# How to go from QByteArrey to a byte pointer in Qt

Tags: qt

I want to convert my QByteArrey into a byte pointer. I found out on the internet how to go the opposite way and i found myself struggling in finding the right way to do it... So can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data() or constData() method.

```
QByteArray ba("Hello world");
char *data = ba.data();
while (*data) {
  cout << "[" << *data << "]" << Qt::endl;
  ++data;
}
```